# jQuery datepicker for 2 months with fixed first month

Tags: jquery, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

I use jQuery datepicker widget to select date. I need to display 2 months 2014-10 and 2014-11 and limit selectable dates to 2014-10-30, 2014-11-02 and 2014-11-03. This is trivial.

```
$(selector).datepicker({
    numberOfMonths: 2,
    dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
    beforeShowDay: function (date) {
        if ($.inArray(date.formatDefault(), 
                ['2014-10-30', '2014-11-02', '2014-11-03']) !== -1) {
            return [true, "", ""];
        } else {
            return [false, "", ""];
        }
    }
});
```

When value of selector field is 2014-10-30 calendar dialog contains october and november (correctly). Then I choose date from november and when I reopen calenar dialog contains months november and december. How to make datepicker to always display october and november? I tried to set `minDate` and `defaultDate` to `'2014-10-01'` and didn't helped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set params:

```
minDate: '2014-10-01',
maxDate: '2014-11-30',
```

or

```
minDate: '2014-10-30',
maxDate: '2014-11-03',
```